# Assigning string to pointer to character

Tags: c#, string, class, pointers, char

I want to store string object to `char *` in C#.Net, how can I achieve that?

My function is

```
xyz(char *c)
{
}
```

I want to pass this string as argument to this function:

```
string s = "Hello"
```

I am using unsafe code in C#.

Comment: No need to use unsafe, and it would be helpful if you showed your code. I don't understand why you don't.

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "Hello";
fixed (char* ptr = s) {
    xyz(ptr);
}
```

Note that you shouldn't really *store* that pointer (in a field etc), as the address will only be *pinned* for the duration of the `fixed` block. You can use it fine inside `xyz`, though.

Just... be nice; mutating `string`s is pretty dangerous.

Also: as noted in the comments: `xyz(ptr, s.Length)` would be strongly recommended.

Comment: Does he need to pass in the `string`s Length?

Comment: @Romoku certainly, if they don't want it to explode: but `xyz` has no parameter for that. Let's hope they add one :)

Answer (score 0):

string will be treated as the array and the char* will point first index of string so you can call your function as
xyz(your string);
i guess it should work